# Force page to go full screen on chrome - iphone

Tags: ios, google-chrome, mobile, fullscreen

I have checked out some libraries as :

BigScreen,
screenfull,

but no luck.

I also see here http://mobilehtml5.org/ that support of the full screen API in chrome for ios is not even mentioned, does that mean that it can't be done?

I would prefer a solid solution, not a workaround like "scroll up" artificially.

Thanks!

Comment: You want to get rid of iOS status bar or Chrome toolbars?

Comment: @zcui93 Practically I want to get into full screen mode. I basically want to run a website for google cardboard so it must be full screen for the viewer to see only the content of the site.